# Windows Service that executes special function at specific time

Tags: c#, .net, timer, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I have a Windows Service that Monitors a Network folder for a file and on Creation moves that File and does some transfiguration.  This works great.

My question is, if a file has not been saved to the Monitored Location by 9:30am I need to have my service send out a reminder email.  I was hoping not to have to write a 2nd program for this which is what seems to be a common suggestion(2nd program with Scheduled Task).

So, what are my options? I assume that I can make this work using a Timer in some fashion but I understand that is not the best idea.  Is there a way to have a Scheduled Task make my Service execute a specific function?

Thanks for any ideas...

EDIT: for reference I am currently researching [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/index.html), just seemed like overkill at first...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong using the timer, use System.Timers.Timer and set interval for example to 5 minutes, and then in Elapsed event check current time, if 9:30 is passed send mail.

Comment: I hate to even ask but System.Timers.Timer or System.Threading.Timer?

Comment: For similar purpose I am using System.Timers (spawns elapsed event in a new thread), for your case I think that there is no real difference or benefit, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, I'd suggest *System.Threading.Timer* in the same service.

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Foo
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private readonly static TimeSpan TIME_OF_DAY = new TimeSpan(9, 30, 0);

    public void Main()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var nextDt = now.Date.AddDays(1).Add(TIME_OF_DAY); 
        _timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, (int)nextDt.Subtract(now).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            // Reminder
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                var nextDt = now.Date.AddDays(1).Add(TIME_OF_DAY);
                _timer.Change((int)nextDt.Subtract(now).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend a second program to do the checking and to send the email since it's not easy to communicate with a service.  It may seem like duplication but it will be easier to develop and maintain in the long run.

Rather than having the *service* send the email, have the *second program* send the email.  If you want to reuse code from the service, add the service project as a reference to the second program.

That may be easier said than done but it should be easier than trying to have the second program communicate with the service in some way since you'd have to wire the communication mechanism yourself.

Comment: So you would write a second program vs using a Timer or similar solution?

Comment: Sure, why not?  Seems simpler that having the service constantly checking to see if it's 9:30 and then executing some special code.  You even said in your question that it's "not the bast idea" to use a timer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two questions in your post.
1. You need a scheduler to check at 9.30 AM everyday
2. If it is not saved you need to notify via email.

Actually Quartz.NET is very simple to use. I am currently using Quartz.NET for one of my schedule tasks to run. You just need to write 4-5 lines of code and have the job scheduling part done.

Coming to your email you can use log4net. Log4net has something called SMTPAppender. All your configurations related to log4net you can specify in your web or app.config itself. Its also very simple and pretty straight forward. A sample log4net configuration for SMTPAppender will look like below:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="SMTPAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SMTPAppender">
      <authentication value="Basic" />
      <to value="xxx@xxx" />
      <from value="yyy@yyy" />
      <username value="user" />
      <password value="pass" />
      <subject value="ERROR" />
      <smtpHost value="host" />
      <port value="25" />
      <lossy value="true" />
      <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
        <threshold value="WARN" />
      </evaluator>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %newline %message%newline%newline%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="INFO"></level>
    </root>
    <logger name="SMTPAppender">
      <level value="INFO"></level>
      <appender-ref ref="SMTPAppender"></appender-ref>
    </logger>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Actually I use ExchangeWebServices for my Emailing which works great.  I will continue to look at Quartz.Net for the timing though.  I am really trying to avoid having such a simple application split across multiple platforms and solutions if possible.